# custom php.ini - nothing seems to work - what do you suggest? FastCGI-php mode - allow_url_fopen OFF

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, fastcgi, plesk

I need to modify the allow_url_fopen value from OFF to ON
i have an hosting account on a shared hosting which uses linux and plesk...
php is running as fastcgi and safe mode is off.
this is the only way i can use this server (except i can switch on php safe mode)
according to `phpinfo()` php.ini file is located here:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc 
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     /etc/php.d
```

php vesrion : `PHP Version 5.3.27`

i used ini_get to see the ini tree:

```
$options = ini_get_all();
print_r($options);
```

this results:

```
[allow_url_fopen] => Array ( [global_value] => [local_value] => [access] => 4 )
```

i tried a few things but i am sure it's not enough or i did something wrong...
1. tried to put a php.ini file in the httpdocs folder and didn't work
2. tried custom cgi script - i don't know if the code was correct:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /etc/php -c /path/to/myweb/httpdocs/php.ini
```

and then called from .htacccess file

```
AddHandler php-cgi .php .htm
Action php-cgi /cgi-bin/php.cgi
```

3. tried all the php `ini_set` but nothing works
4. tried in .htaccess

```
php_value allow_url_fopen On
php_value allow_url_fopen 1
```

nothing seems to work... any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously cannot use Apache settings file to change PHP settings if you don't run PHP as Apache module.

The file needs to be called [.user.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php), not `php.ini` (since it's a shared hosting, you cannot edit any server-wide settings file).

But if we have a look at the [list of directives](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) we can see that `allow_url_fopen` is categorised as `PHP_INI_SYSTEM`. That [means](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) that it's a global server setting, thus you don't have permission to change it. You're out of luck: your hosting account does not offer a feature your current code needs.

Comment: i managed to change php to run as apache module with safe mode off, this option was available before but the changes didn't actually happen. now it works. will this give me some chances ?

Comment: @john - Not sure I follow you. How can that help?

Comment: i have no idea, i'm stuck and don't know what to do. after changing the php to run as apache module, importing files on my website admin pannel is not working anymore...

Comment: Why did you do that? Do you need clarifications about anything in my answer?